# R merge two datasets based on specific columns with added condition

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

**Both Uwe's and GKi's answer are correct. Gki received the bounty because Uwe was late for that, but Uwe's solution runs about 15x as fast**

I have two datasets that contain scores for different patients on multiple measuring moments like so:

```
df1 <- data.frame("ID" = c("patient1","patient1","patient1","patient1","patient2","patient3"),
                  "Days" = c(0,25,235,353,100,538),
                  "Score" = c(NA,2,3,4,5,6), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame("ID" = c("patient1","patient1","patient1","patient1","patient2","patient2","patient3"),
                  "Days" = c(0,25,248,353,100,150,503),
                  "Score" = c(1,10,3,4,5,7,6), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df1
        ID Days Score
1 patient1    0    NA
2 patient1   25     2
3 patient1  235     3
4 patient1  353     4
5 patient2  100     5
6 patient3  538     6

> df2
        ID Days Score
1 patient1    0     1
2 patient1   25    10
3 patient1  248     3
4 patient1  353     4
5 patient2  100     5
6 patient2  150     7
7 patient3  503     6
```

Column `ID` shows the patient ID, column `Days` shows the moment of measurement (Days since patient inclusion) and column `Score` shows the measured score. Both datasets show the same data but in different moments in time (df1 was 2 years ago, df2 has the same data with updates from this year).

I have to compare the scores for each patient and each moment between both datasets. However, in some cases the `Days` variable has minor changes over time, so comparing the dataset by a simple join does not work. Example:

```
library(dplyr)

> full_join(df1, df2, by=c("ID","Days")) %>% 
+   arrange(.[[1]], as.numeric(.[[2]]))

        ID Days Score.x Score.y
1 patient1    0      NA       1
2 patient1   25       2      10
3 patient1  235       3      NA
4 patient1  248      NA       3
5 patient1  353       4       4
6 patient2  100       5       5
7 patient2  150      NA       7
8 patient3  503      NA       6
9 patient3  538       6      NA
```

Here, rows 3 and 4 contain data for the same measurement (with score 3) but are not joined because the values for the `Days` column are different (235 vs 248).

**Question:** I'm looking for a way to set a threshold on the second column (say 30 days) which would result in the following output:

```
> threshold <- 30
> *** insert join code ***

        ID Days Score.x Score.y
1 patient1    0      NA       1
2 patient1   25       2      10
3 patient1  248       3       3
4 patient1  353       4       4
5 patient2  100       5       5
6 patient2  150      NA       7
7 patient3  503      NA       6
8 patient3  538       6      NA
```

This output shows that rows 3 and 4 of the previous output have been merged (because 248-235 < 30) and have taken the value for `Days` of the second df (248).

Three main conditions to keep in mind are:

- Consecutive days that are within the threshold from **within the same df (rows 1 and 2) are not merged**.
- In some cases, up to four values for the `Days` variable exist in the same dataframe and thus should not be merged. It might be the case that one of these values does exist within the treshold in the other dataframe, and these will have to be merged. See row 3 in the example below.
- Each score/days/patient combination can only be used once. If a merge satisfies all conditions but there is still a double-merge possible, the first one should be used.

```
> df1
        ID Days Score
1 patient1    0     1
2 patient1    5     2
3 patient1   10     3
4 patient1   15     4
5 patient1   50     5

> df2
        ID Days Score
1 patient1    0     1
2 patient1    5     2
3 patient1   12     3
4 patient1   15     4
5 patient1   50     5

> df_combined
        ID Days Score.x Score.y
1 patient1    0       1       1
2 patient1    5       2       2
3 patient1   12       3       3
4 patient1   15       4       4
5 patient1   50       5       5
```

**EDIT FOR CHINSOON12**

```
> df1
          ID Days Score
 1: patient1    0     1
 2: patient1  116     2
 3: patient1  225     3
 4: patient1  309     4
 5: patient1  351     5
 6: patient2    0     6
 7: patient2   49     7
> df2
          ID Days Score
 1: patient1    0    11
 2: patient1   86    12
 3: patient1  195    13
 4: patient1  279    14
 5: patient1  315    15
 6: patient2    0    16
 7: patient2   91    17
 8: patient2  117    18
```

I wrapped your solution in a function like so:

```
testSO2 <- function(DT1,DT2) {
    setDT(DT1);setDT(DT2)
    names(DT1) <- c("ID","Days","X")
    names(DT2) <- c("ID","Days","Y")
    DT1$Days <- as.numeric(DT1$Days)
    DT2$Days <- as.numeric(DT2$Days)
    DT1[, c("s1", "e1", "s2", "e2") := .(Days - 30L, Days + 30L, Days, Days)]
    DT2[, c("s1", "e1", "s2", "e2") := .(Days, Days, Days - 30L, Days + 30L)]
    byk <- c("ID", "s1", "e1")
    setkeyv(DT1, byk)
    setkeyv(DT2, byk)
    o1 <- foverlaps(DT1, DT2)
    
    byk <- c("ID", "s2", "e2")
    setkeyv(DT1, byk)
    setkeyv(DT2, byk)
    o2 <- foverlaps(DT2, DT1)
    
    olaps <- funion(o1, setcolorder(o2, names(o1)))[
        is.na(Days), Days := i.Days]
    
    outcome <- olaps[, {
        if (all(!is.na(Days)) && any(Days == i.Days)) {
            s <- .SD[Days == i.Days, .(Days = Days[1L],
                                       X = X[1L],
                                       Y = Y[1L])]
        } else {
            s <- .SD[, .(Days = max(Days, i.Days), X, Y)]
        }
        unique(s)
    },
    keyby = .(ID, md = pmax(Days, i.Days))][, md := NULL][]
    return(outcome)
}
```

Which results in:

```
> testSO2(df1,df2)
          ID Days  X  Y
 1: patient1    0  1 11
 2: patient1  116  2 12
 3: patient1  225  3 13
 4: patient1  309  4 14
 5: patient1  315  4 15
 6: patient1  351  5 NA
 7: patient2    0  6 16
 8: patient2   49  7 NA
 9: patient2   91 NA 17
10: patient2  117 NA 18
```

As you can see, rows 4 and 5 are wrong. The value for `Score` in df1 is used twice (4). The correct output around those rows should be as follows, as each score (X or Y in this case) can only be used once:

```
          ID Days  X  Y
 4: patient1  309  4 14
 5: patient1  315 NA 15
 6: patient1  351  5 NA
```

Code for dataframes below.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(c("patient1", "patient2"), c(5L, 2L)),
  Days = c("0", "116", "225", "309", "351", "0", "49"),
  Score = 1:7
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(c("patient1", "patient2"), c(5L, 3L)),
  Days = c("0", "86", "195", "279", "315", "0", "91", "117"),
  Score = 11:18
)
```

Comment: Have you tried taking a different approach to the problem? You may be better off if there is a way you can label what a measurement represents. The solution you're asking for is susceptible to failure from edge cases.

Comment: I have to compare many different variables on content so labelling is not really an option. I chose a numeric score here for clarity, but really the content of the 3rd column does not really matter. Merging of the second column is the main problem

Comment: This didn't happen in your data set, but: what if in rows 3 and 4 of your first joined data set, you'd have had `Score.x = 3` and `Score.y = 4`? Would you still want to discard one of the measurements in that case?

Comment: If I understand you correctly the measurement wouldn't be discarded. In df1 the measurement is 3 with days 235, and in df2 the measurement is 4 with days 248. The days in this case would be joined together but the measurements would not, so the final result would be ```patient1    248     3      4```

Comment: Got it. Follow-up question: regarding your first joined data frame, what if you'd had a row between rows 1 and 2 (call it row 1.5) with `ID = patient1`, `Days = 13`, `Score.x = 1`, and `Score.y = NA`? Would you only want row 2 to merge with row 1.5, even though it is still also within 30 days of row 1?

Comment: Interesting. In the case that multiple rows are within 30days of each other, the data of the first one should be used. I believe this never happens in the real data though

Comment: Should every time the nearest Day be taken or should the total difference in days minimized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being late to the party, here is a solution which uses a *full outer join* with *subsequent grouping and aggregation* of rows according to OP's rules.

```
library(data.table)
threshold <- 30
# full outer join
m <- merge(setDT(df1)[, o := 1L], setDT(df2)[, o := 2L], 
           by = c("ID", "Days"), all = TRUE)
# reorder rows
setorder(m, ID, Days)
# create grouping variable
m[, g := rleid(ID,
               cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Days) > threshold)),
               !is.na(o.x) & !is.na(o.y),
               cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(fcoalesce(o.x, o.y)) == 0L))
)][, g := rleid(g, (rowid(g) - 1L) %/% 2)][]
# collapse rows where required
m[, .(ID = last(ID), Days = last(Days), 
      Score.x = last(na.omit(Score.x)), 
      Score.y = last(na.omit(Score.y)))
  , by = g][, g := NULL][]
```

For OP's first test case we get

> ```
>          ID Days Score.x Score.y
> 1: patient1    0      NA       1
> 2: patient1   25       2      10
> 3: patient1  248       3       3
> 4: patient1  353       4       4
> 5: patient2  100       5       5
> 6: patient2  150      NA       7
> 7: patient3  503      NA       6
> 8: patient3  538       6      NA
> ```

as expected.

#### Verification with other uses cases

With OP's 2nd test case

```
df1 <- data.table(ID = rep("patient1", 5L), Days = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 50), Score = 1:5)
df2 <- data.table(ID = rep("patient1", 5L), Days = c(0, 5, 12, 15, 50), Score = 1:5)
```

we get

> ```
>          ID Days Score.x Score.y
> 1: patient1    0       1       1
> 2: patient1    5       2       2
> 3: patient1   12       3       3
> 4: patient1   15       4       4
> 5: patient1   50       5       5
> ```

With OP's 3rd test case (which was used to discus [chinsoon12's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62215672/3817004))

```
df1 <- data.table(ID = paste0("patient", c(rep(1, 5L), 2, 2)), 
                  Days = c(0, 116, 225, 309, 351, 0, 49), Score = 1:7)
df2 <- data.table(ID = paste0("patient", c(rep(1, 5L), 2, 2, 2)), 
                  Days = c(0, 86, 195, 279, 315, 0, 91, 117), Score = 11:18)
```

we get

> ```
>           ID Days Score.x Score.y
>  1: patient1    0       1      11
>  2: patient1  116       2      12
>  3: patient1  225       3      13
>  4: patient1  309       4      14
>  5: patient1  315      NA      15
>  6: patient1  351       5      NA
>  7: patient2    0       6      16
>  8: patient2   49       7      NA
>  9: patient2   91      NA      17
> 10: patient2  117      NA      18
> ```

as expected by the OP (see row 5 in particular)

Finally, my own test case has 5 "overlapping days" between 233 and 248 to verify that this case will be treated

```
df1 <- data.table(ID = paste0("patient", c(rep(1, 6L), 2, 3)),
                  Days = c(0,1,25,235,237,353,100,538),
                  Score = c(NA, 2:8))
df2 <- data.table(ID = paste0("patient", c(rep(1, 6L), 2, 2, 3)),
                  Days = c(0, 25, 233, 234, 248, 353, 100, 150, 503),
                  Score = 11:19)
```

we get

> ```
>           ID Days Score.x Score.y
>  1: patient1    0      NA      11    # exact match
>  2: patient1    1       2      NA    # overlapping, not collapsed
>  3: patient1   25       3      12    # exact match
>  4: patient1  233      NA      13    # overlapping, not collapsed
>  5: patient1  235       4      14    # overlapping, collapsed
>  6: patient1  248       5      15    # overlapping, collapsed
>  7: patient1  353       6      16    # exact match
>  8: patient2  100       7      17    # exact match
>  9: patient2  150      NA      18    # not overlapping
> 10: patient3  503      NA      19    # not overlapping
> 11: patient3  538       8      NA    # not overlapping
> ```

#### Explanation

The full outer join `merge(..., all = TRUE)` finds exact matches on the same ID and day but includes all other rows from both datasets without matches.

Before joining, each dataset gets an additional column `o` to indicate the *origin* of each `Score`.

The result is ordered because the subsequent operations depend on the correct row order.

So, with my own test case we get

```
m <- merge(setDT(df1)[, o := 1L], setDT(df2)[, o := 2L], 
           by = c("ID", "Days"), all = TRUE)
setorder(m, ID, Days)[]
```

> ```
>           ID Days Score.x o.x Score.y o.y
>  1: patient1    0      NA   1      11   2
>  2: patient1    1       2   1      NA  NA
>  3: patient1   25       3   1      12   2
>  4: patient1  233      NA  NA      13   2
>  5: patient1  234      NA  NA      14   2
>  6: patient1  235       4   1      NA  NA
>  7: patient1  237       5   1      NA  NA
>  8: patient1  248      NA  NA      15   2
>  9: patient1  353       6   1      16   2
> 10: patient2  100       7   1      17   2
> 11: patient2  150      NA  NA      18   2
> 12: patient3  503      NA  NA      19   2
> 13: patient3  538       8   1      NA  NA
> ```

Now, a grouping variable is created using `rleid()`:

```
m[, g := rleid(ID,
               cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Days) > threshold)),
               !is.na(o.x) & !is.na(o.y),
               cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(fcoalesce(o.x, o.y)) == 0L))
)][, g := rleid(g, (rowid(g) - 1L) %/% 2)][]
```

The group counter is advanced, when one of the following conditions is met:

- the `ID` changes
- within an `ID`, when there is gap of more than 30 days between consecutive `Days` (so rows with a gap of 30 days or less within an ID belong to one group or are "overlapping")
- when a row is a direct match,
- when consecutive rows have the same origin, thereby identifying streaks of rows of alternating origin, e.g., `1, 2, 1, 2, ...` or `2, 1, 2, 1, ...`
- and, finally, within above streaks, count pairs of rows of alternating origin, e.g., one row from `df1` followed by a row from `df2`or one row from `df2` followed by a row from `df1`.

The last condition has not been explicitely stated by the OP but is my interpretation of

> *Each score/days/patient combination can only be used once. If a merge satisfies all conditions but there is still a double-merge possible,
>   the first one should be used.*

It ensures that *at most two rows, each from different datasets* are being collapsed.

After grouping we get

> ```
>           ID Days Score.x o.x Score.y o.y  g
>  1: patient1    0      NA   1      11   2  1
>  2: patient1    1       2   1      NA  NA  2
>  3: patient1   25       3   1      12   2  3
>  4: patient1  233      NA  NA      13   2  4
>  5: patient1  234      NA  NA      14   2  5
>  6: patient1  235       4   1      NA  NA  5
>  7: patient1  237       5   1      NA  NA  6
>  8: patient1  248      NA  NA      15   2  6
>  9: patient1  353       6   1      16   2  7
> 10: patient2  100       7   1      17   2  8
> 11: patient2  150      NA  NA      18   2  9
> 12: patient3  503      NA  NA      19   2 10
> 13: patient3  538       8   1      NA  NA 11
> ```

Most of the groups contain only one row, a few contain 2 rows which are collapsed in the final step (aggregate by group, return the desired columns and remove the grouping variable `g`).

#### Improved code

Aggregating by group requires that for each group only one value (vector of length 1) is returned for each column. (Otherwise, the group result would consist of multiple rows.) The implementation above uses `last()` on all 4 columns for the sake of simplicity.

`last(Days)` is equivalent to `max(Days)` because the dataset is ordered.

However, if I understand correctly the OP prefers to return the `Days` value from `df2` (although the OP has mentioned  that `max(Days)` is acceptable as well).

In order to return the `Days` value from `df2` the aggregation step needs to modified: If the group size `.N` is larger than 1, we pick the `Days` value from the row which originates from `df2`, i.e. where `o.y == 2`.

```
# collapse rows where required
m[, .(ID = last(ID), 
      Days = last(if (.N > 1) Days[which(o.y == 2)] else Days), 
      Score.x = last(na.omit(Score.x)), 
      Score.y = last(na.omit(Score.y)))
  , by = g][, g := NULL][]
```

This will return

> ```
>           ID Days Score.x Score.y
>  1: patient1    0      NA      11
>  2: patient1    1       2      NA
>  3: patient1   25       3      12
>  4: patient1  233      NA      13
>  5: patient1  234       4      14
>  6: patient1  248       5      15
>  7: patient1  353       6      16
>  8: patient2  100       7      17
>  9: patient2  150      NA      18
> 10: patient3  503      NA      19
> 11: patient3  538       8      NA
> ```

Now the `Days` value 234 in collapsed row 5 has been picked from `df2`.

For the `Score` columns the use of `last()` should not matter at all, because there should be only one non-NA value in a group of 2 rows. So, `na.omit()` should return only a single value and `last()` is just for consistency, probably.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough and precise answer. I'm going to run it through my data and i'll get back to you. I noticed gki's answer gets 1 row wrong in your latest example so this might be a better solution. The bounty has already been given out unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that this will happen because the checkmark was not withdrawn from the first answer.

Answer (score 6):

A *base* solution using `lapply` to find where differences in *Days* is below *threshold* and make an `expand.grid` to get all possible combinations. Afterwards remove those which would pick the same twice or are picking behind another one. From those calculate the day difference and pick the line which has the consecutive lowest difference. Afterwards `rbind` the not matched from df2.

```
threshold <- 30
nmScore <- threshold
x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(c(df1$ID, df2$ID)), function(ID) {
  x <- df1[df1$ID == ID,]
  y <- df2[df2$ID == ID,]
  if(nrow(x) == 0) {return(data.frame(ID=ID, y[1,-1][NA,], y[,-1]))}
  if(nrow(y) == 0) {return(data.frame(ID=ID, x[,-1], x[1,-1][NA,]))}
  x <- x[order(x$Days),]
  y <- y[order(y$Days),]
  z <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(x$Days, function(z) c(NA,
         which(abs(z - y$Days) < threshold))))
  z <- z[!apply(z, 1, function(z) {anyDuplicated(z[!is.na(z)]) > 0 ||
         any(diff(z[!is.na(z)]) < 1)}), , drop = FALSE]
  s <- as.data.frame(sapply(seq_len(ncol(z)), function(j) {
         abs(x$Days[j] - y$Days[z[,j]])}))
  s[is.na(s)] <- nmScore
  s <- matrix(apply(s, 1, sort), nrow(s), byrow = TRUE)
  i <- rep(TRUE, nrow(s))
  for(j in seq_len(ncol(s))) {i[i]  <- s[i,j] == min(s[i,j])}
  i <- unlist(z[which.max(i),])
  j <- setdiff(seq_len(nrow(y)), i)
  rbind(data.frame(ID=ID, x[,-1], y[i, -1]),
  if(length(j) > 0) data.frame(ID=ID, x[1,-1][NA,], y[j, -1], row.names=NULL))
}))
x <- x[order(x[,1], ifelse(is.na(x[,2]), x[,4], x[,2])),]
```

Data:

0..First test case from Boris Ruwe, 
1..2nd test case from Boris Ruwe, 
2..3nd test case from Boris Ruwe, 
3..Test case from Uwe, 
4..Test case from Boris Ruwe from [R rolling join two data.tables with error margin on join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62211431/10488504), 
5..Test case from GKi.

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("0patient1", "0patient1", "0patient1", 
"0patient1", "0patient2", "0patient3", "1patient1", "1patient1", 
"1patient1", "1patient1", "1patient1", "2patient1", "2patient1", 
"2patient1", "2patient1", "2patient1", "2patient2", "2patient2", 
"3patient1", "3patient1", "3patient1", "3patient1", "3patient1", 
"3patient1", "3patient2", "3patient3", "4patient1", "4patient1", 
"4patient1", "4patient1", "4patient2", "4patient3", "5patient1", 
"5patient1", "5patient1", "5patient2"), Days = c(0, 25, 235, 
353, 100, 538, 0, 5, 10, 15, 50, 0, 116, 225, 309, 351, 0, 49, 
0, 1, 25, 235, 237, 353, 100, 538, 0, 10, 25, 340, 100, 538, 
3, 6, 10, 1), Score = c(NA, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, NA, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, NA, 2, 3, 99, 5, 6, 
1, 2, 3, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("0patient1", "0patient1", "0patient1", 
"0patient1", "0patient2", "0patient2", "0patient3", "1patient1", 
"1patient1", "1patient1", "1patient1", "1patient1", "2patient1", 
"2patient1", "2patient1", "2patient1", "2patient1", "2patient2", 
"2patient2", "2patient2", "3patient1", "3patient1", "3patient1", 
"3patient1", "3patient1", "3patient1", "3patient2", "3patient2", 
"3patient3", "4patient1", "4patient1", "4patient1", "4patient1", 
"4patient2", "4patient2", "4patient3", "5patient1", "5patient1", 
"5patient1", "5patient3"), Days = c(0, 25, 248, 353, 100, 150, 
503, 0, 5, 12, 15, 50, 0, 86, 195, 279, 315, 0, 91, 117, 0, 25, 
233, 234, 248, 353, 100, 150, 503, 0, 10, 25, 353, 100, 150, 
503, 1, 4, 8, 1), Score = c(1, 10, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 1, 10, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 11, 12, 13, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = "data.frame")
df1
#          ID Days Score
#1  0patient1    0    NA
#2  0patient1   25     2
#3  0patient1  235     3
#4  0patient1  353     4
#5  0patient2  100     5
#6  0patient3  538     6
#7  1patient1    0     1
#8  1patient1    5     2
#9  1patient1   10     3
#10 1patient1   15     4
#11 1patient1   50     5
#12 2patient1    0     1
#13 2patient1  116     2
#14 2patient1  225     3
#15 2patient1  309     4
#16 2patient1  351     5
#17 2patient2    0     6
#18 2patient2   49     7
#19 3patient1    0    NA
#20 3patient1    1     2
#21 3patient1   25     3
#22 3patient1  235     4
#23 3patient1  237     5
#24 3patient1  353     6
#25 3patient2  100     7
#26 3patient3  538     8
#27 4patient1    0    NA
#28 4patient1   10     2
#29 4patient1   25     3
#30 4patient1  340    99
#31 4patient2  100     5
#32 4patient3  538     6
#33 5patient1    3     1
#34 5patient1    6     2
#35 5patient1   10     3
#36 5patient2    1     1

df2
#          ID Days Score
#1  0patient1    0     1
#2  0patient1   25    10
#3  0patient1  248     3
#4  0patient1  353     4
#5  0patient2  100     5
#6  0patient2  150     7
#7  0patient3  503     6
#8  1patient1    0     1
#9  1patient1    5     2
#10 1patient1   12     3
#11 1patient1   15     4
#12 1patient1   50     5
#13 2patient1    0    11
#14 2patient1   86    12
#15 2patient1  195    13
#16 2patient1  279    14
#17 2patient1  315    15
#18 2patient2    0    16
#19 2patient2   91    17
#20 2patient2  117    18
#21 3patient1    0    11
#22 3patient1   25    12
#23 3patient1  233    13
#24 3patient1  234    14
#25 3patient1  248    15
#26 3patient1  353    16
#27 3patient2  100    17
#28 3patient2  150    18
#29 3patient3  503    19
#30 4patient1    0     1
#31 4patient1   10    10
#32 4patient1   25     3
#33 4patient1  353     4
#34 4patient2  100     5
#35 4patient2  150     7
#36 4patient3  503     6
#37 5patient1    1    11
#38 5patient1    4    12
#39 5patient1    8    13
#40 5patient3    1     1
```

Result:

```
#           ID Days Score Days.1 Score.1
#1   0patient1    0    NA      0       1
#2   0patient1   25     2     25      10
#3   0patient1  235     3    248       3
#4   0patient1  353     4    353       4
#5   0patient2  100     5    100       5
#110 0patient2   NA    NA    150       7
#111 0patient3   NA    NA    503       6
#6   0patient3  538     6     NA      NA
#7   1patient1    0     1      0       1
#8   1patient1    5     2      5       2
#9   1patient1   10     3     12       3
#10  1patient1   15     4     15       4
#11  1patient1   50     5     50       5
#12  2patient1    0     1      0      11
#112 2patient1   NA    NA     86      12
#13  2patient1  116     2     NA      NA
#210 2patient1   NA    NA    195      13
#14  2patient1  225     3     NA      NA
#37  2patient1   NA    NA    279      14
#15  2patient1  309     4    315      15
#16  2patient1  351     5     NA      NA
#17  2patient2    0     6      0      16
#18  2patient2   49     7     NA      NA
#113 2patient2   NA    NA     91      17
#211 2patient2   NA    NA    117      18
#19  3patient1    0    NA      0      11
#20  3patient1    1     2     NA      NA
#21  3patient1   25     3     25      12
#114 3patient1   NA    NA    233      13
#22  3patient1  235     4    234      14
#23  3patient1  237     5    248      15
#24  3patient1  353     6    353      16
#25  3patient2  100     7    100      17
#115 3patient2   NA    NA    150      18
#116 3patient3   NA    NA    503      19
#26  3patient3  538     8     NA      NA
#27  4patient1    0    NA      0       1
#28  4patient1   10     2     10      10
#29  4patient1   25     3     25       3
#30  4patient1  340    99    353       4
#31  4patient2  100     5    100       5
#117 4patient2   NA    NA    150       7
#118 4patient3   NA    NA    503       6
#32  4patient3  538     6     NA      NA
#119 5patient1   NA    NA      1      11
#33  5patient1    3     1      4      12
#34  5patient1    6     2      8      13
#35  5patient1   10     3     NA      NA
#36  5patient2    1     1     NA      NA
#NA  5patient3   NA    NA      1       1
```

Formatted result:

```
data.frame(ID=x[,1], Days=ifelse(is.na(x[,2]), x[,4], x[,2]),
 Score.x=x[,3], Score.y=x[,5])
#          ID Days Score.x Score.y
#1  0patient1    0      NA       1
#2  0patient1   25       2      10
#3  0patient1  235       3       3
#4  0patient1  353       4       4
#5  0patient2  100       5       5
#6  0patient2  150      NA       7
#7  0patient3  503      NA       6
#8  0patient3  538       6      NA
#9  1patient1    0       1       1
#10 1patient1    5       2       2
#11 1patient1   10       3       3
#12 1patient1   15       4       4
#13 1patient1   50       5       5
#14 2patient1    0       1      11
#15 2patient1   86      NA      12
#16 2patient1  116       2      NA
#17 2patient1  195      NA      13
#18 2patient1  225       3      NA
#19 2patient1  279      NA      14
#20 2patient1  309       4      15
#21 2patient1  351       5      NA
#22 2patient2    0       6      16
#23 2patient2   49       7      NA
#24 2patient2   91      NA      17
#25 2patient2  117      NA      18
#26 3patient1    0      NA      11
#27 3patient1    1       2      NA
#28 3patient1   25       3      12
#29 3patient1  233      NA      13
#30 3patient1  235       4      14
#31 3patient1  237       5      15
#32 3patient1  353       6      16
#33 3patient2  100       7      17
#34 3patient2  150      NA      18
#35 3patient3  503      NA      19
#36 3patient3  538       8      NA
#37 4patient1    0      NA       1
#38 4patient1   10       2      10
#39 4patient1   25       3       3
#40 4patient1  340      99       4
#41 4patient2  100       5       5
#42 4patient2  150      NA       7
#43 4patient3  503      NA       6
#44 4patient3  538       6      NA
#45 5patient1    1      NA      11
#46 5patient1    3       1      12
#47 5patient1    6       2      13
#48 5patient1   10       3      NA
#49 5patient2    1       1      NA
#50 5patient3    1      NA       1
```

Alternatives to get `Days`:

```
#From df1 and in case it is NA I took it from df2
data.frame(ID=x[,1], Days=ifelse(is.na(x[,2]), x[,4], x[,2]),
 Score.x=x[,3], Score.y=x[,5])

#From df2 and in case it is NA I took it from df1
data.frame(ID=x[,1], Days=ifelse(is.na(x[,4]), x[,2], x[,4]),
 Score.x=x[,3], Score.y=x[,5])

#Mean
data.frame(ID=x[,1], Days=rowMeans(x[,c(2,4)], na.rm=TRUE),
 Score.x=x[,3], Score.y=x[,5])
```

In case the *total* difference in days should be minimized, allowing not to take the nearest, a possible way will be:

```
threshold <- 30
nmScore <- threshold
x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(c(df1$ID, df2$ID)), function(ID) {
  x <- df1[df1$ID == ID,]
  y <- df2[df2$ID == ID,]
  x <- x[order(x$Days),]
  y <- y[order(y$Days),]
  if(nrow(x) == 0) {return(data.frame(ID=ID, y[1,-1][NA,], y[,-1]))}
  if(nrow(y) == 0) {return(data.frame(ID=ID, x[,-1], x[1,-1][NA,]))}
  z <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(x$Days, function(z) c(NA,
         which(abs(z - y$Days) < threshold))))
  z <- z[!apply(z, 1, function(z) {anyDuplicated(z[!is.na(z)]) > 0 ||
         any(diff(z[!is.na(z)]) < 1)}), , drop = FALSE]
  s <- as.data.frame(sapply(seq_len(ncol(z)), function(j) {
         abs(x$Days[j] - y$Days[z[,j]])}))
  s[is.na(s)] <- nmScore
  i <- unlist(z[which.min(rowSums(s)),])
  j <- setdiff(seq_len(nrow(y)), i)
  rbind(data.frame(ID=ID, x[,-1], y[i, -1]),
  if(length(j) > 0) data.frame(ID=ID, x[1,-1][NA,], y[j, -1], row.names=NULL))
}))
x <- x[order(x[,1], ifelse(is.na(x[,2]), x[,4], x[,2])),]
```

Comment: It seems to work, testing on a larger dataset at the moment.. Meanwhile i'm getting some warnings which I don't really understand, could you elaborate?
warning 1:
```24: In min(z) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf```

warning 2:
```25: In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
```

Comment: I've yet to find an error, so I'm going to accept this as an answer for now. Thank you very much!
One more thing, is it possible for the ```Days``` value to use the value of df2, instead of using the highest as it does currently?

Comment: Currently I took `Days` from `df1` and in case it is `NA` I took it from `df2`. You want to take them from `df2` and in case they are `NA` take them from `df1`? `x` holds both informations. The first block is form `df1`, the second from `df2`.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a data cleaning exercise of a realistic but messy dataset that unfortunately, most of us have experience with before. Here is another `data.table` option:

```
DT1[, c("Xrn", "s1", "e1", "s2", "e2") := .(.I, Days - 30L, Days + 30L, Days, Days)]
DT2[, c("Yrn", "s1", "e1", "s2", "e2") := .(.I, Days, Days, Days - 30L, Days + 30L)]
byk <- c("ID", "s1", "e1")
setkeyv(DT1, byk)
setkeyv(DT2, byk)
o1 <- foverlaps(DT1, DT2)

byk <- c("ID", "s2", "e2")
setkeyv(DT1, byk)
setkeyv(DT2, byk)
o2 <- foverlaps(DT2, DT1)

olaps <- funion(o1, setcolorder(o2, names(o1)))[
    is.na(Days), Days := i.Days]

ans <- olaps[, {
        if (any(Days == i.Days)) {
            .SD[Days == i.Days, 
                .(Days=Days[1L], Xrn=Xrn[1L], Yrn=Yrn[1L], X=X[1L], Y=Y[1L])]
        } else {
            .SD[, .(Days=md, Xrn=Xrn[1L], Yrn=Yrn[1L], X=X[1L], Y=Y[1L])]
        }
    },
    keyby = .(ID, md = pmax(Days, i.Days))]

#or also ans[duplicated(Xrn), X := NA_integer_][duplicated(Yrn), Y := NA_integer_]
ans[rowid(Xrn) > 1L, X := NA_integer_]
ans[rowid(Yrn) > 1L, Y := NA_integer_]
ans[, c("md", "Xrn", "Yrn") := NULL][]
```

output for dataset below:

```
   ID Days  X  Y
1:  1    0  1 11
2:  1   10  2 12
3:  1   25  3 13
4:  1  248  4 14
5:  1  353  5 15
6:  2  100  6 16
7:  2  150 NA 17
8:  3  503 NA 18
9:  3  538  7 NA
```

output for second dataset in OP's edit:

```
          ID Days  X  Y
 1: patient1    0  1 11
 2: patient1  116  2 12
 3: patient1  225  3 13
 4: patient1  309  4 14
 5: patient1  315 NA 15
 6: patient1  351  5 NA
 7: patient2    0  6 16
 8: patient2   49  7 NA
 9: patient2   91 NA 17
10: patient2  117 NA 18
```

data (i have added more data from the other linked post and also simplify the data for easier viewing):

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3),
    Days = c(0,10,25,235,353,100,538))[, X := .I]
DT2 <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3),
    Days = c(0,10,25,248,353,100,150,503))[, Y := .I + 10L]
```

Explanation:

1. perform 2 overlapping joins using each table as the left table in turn.
2. Union the 2 results from before setting NA days in right table to those from left table.
3. Group by patient and overlapping dates. If identical dates exist, then keep records. Else use the maximum date.
4. Each Score should only be used once, hence remove duplicates.

Please let me know if you find cases where this approach is not giving the correct results.

Comment: This is the best one so far. I tested it on a sample piece of my data and there is only 1 error. I'll edit it in my post here

Comment: @BorisRuwe, i have added some code to prevent reuse of the score. please let me know if you find more cases where this approach is wrong.

Comment: There are still issues that arise; if a new time moment is inserted the Xrn and Yrn row values get out of sync, and thus lots of data is set to NA in ```ans[rowid(X) > 1L, X := NA_integer_]```. Do you have some time to chat?

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215510/room-for-boris-ruwe-and-chinsoon12

Answer (score 3):

This code lets you give a threshold then merges the scores from df1 into df1 as a new column. It will only add in scores that fall within single range of the scores in df2 +/- the threshold. Note that it is not possible to have all the scores joined since there is no threshold where all the scores match uniquely.

```
threshold <- 40
WhereDF1inDF2 <- apply(sapply(lapply(df2$Days, function(x) (x+threshold):(x-threshold)), function(y) df1$Days %in% y),1,which)
useable <- sapply(WhereDF1inDF2, function(x) length(x) ==1 )
df2$Score1 <- NA
df2$Score1[unlist(WhereDF1inDF2[useable])] <- df1$Score[useable]

> df2
        ID Days Score Score1
1 patient1    0     1     NA
2 patient1   25    10     NA
3 patient1  248     3      3
4 patient1  353     4      4
5 patient2  100     5      5
6 patient2  150     7     NA
7 patient3  503     6      6
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
#convert df1 and df2 to data.table format
setDT(df1);setDT(df2)
#set colnames for later on 
#  (add .df1/.df2 suffix after Days and Score-colnamaes)
cols <- c("Days", "Score")
setnames(df1, cols, paste0( cols, ".df1" ) )
setnames(df2, cols, paste0( cols, ".df2" ) )
#update df1 with new measures from df2 (and df2 with df1)
# copies are made, to prevent changes in df1 and df2
dt1 <- copy(df1)[ df2, `:=`(Days.df2 = i.Days.df2, Score.df2 = i.Score.df2), on = .(ID, Days.df1 = Days.df2), roll = 30]
dt2 <- copy(df2)[ df1, `:=`(Days.df1 = i.Days.df1, Score.df1 = i.Score.df1), on = .(ID, Days.df2 = Days.df1), roll = -30]
#rowbind by columnnames (here the .df1/.df2 suffix is needed!), only keep unique rows
ans <- unique( rbindlist( list( dt1, dt2), use.names = TRUE ) )
#wrangle data to get to desired output
ans[, Days := ifelse( is.na(Days.df2), Days.df1, Days.df2 ) ]
ans <- ans[, .(Days, Score.x = Score.df1, Score.y = Score.df2 ), by = .(ID) ]
setkey( ans, ID, Days )  #for sorting; setorder() can also be used.
#          ID Days Score.x Score.y
# 1: patient1    0      NA       1
# 2: patient1   25       2      10
# 3: patient1  248       3       3
# 4: patient1  353       4       4
# 5: patient2  100       5       5
# 6: patient2  150      NA       7
# 7: patient3  503      NA       6
# 8: patient3  538       6      NA
```

Comment: This worked in the example I initially gave, but it doesn't work on any of the real data (or a portion of it, see most recent edit in my post). It only correctly merges the first data for each patient somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works on your sample data.  Based on your conditions it should work on your full data.  For other exceptions, you can adjust `df31` and `df32`.

```
df1 <- data.frame("ID" = c("patient1","patient1","patient1","patient1","patient2","patient3"),
                  "Days1" = c(0,25,235,353,100,538),
                  "Score1" = c(NA,2,3,4,5,6), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame("ID" = c("patient1","patient1","patient1","patient1","patient2","patient2","patient3"),
                  "Days2" = c(0,25,248,353,100,150,503),
                  "Score2" = c(1,10,3,4,5,7,6), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

##  define a dummy sequence for each patient
df11 <- df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(ptseq = row_number())
df21 <- df2 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(ptseq = row_number())

df3 <- dplyr::full_join(df11, df21, by=c("ID","ptseq")) %>% 
         arrange(.[[1]], as.numeric(.[[2]]))

df31 <- df3 %>% mutate(Days=Days2, diff=Days1-Days2) %>% 
    mutate(Score1=ifelse(abs(diff)>30, NA, Score1))
df32 <- df3 %>% mutate(diff=Days1-Days2) %>%
     mutate(Days = case_when(abs(diff)>30 ~ Days1), Score2=c(NA), Days2=c(NA)) %>% 
     subset(!is.na(Days))

df <- rbind(df31,df32) %>%  select(ID, ptseq, Days, Score1, Score2) %>% 
         arrange(.[[1]], as.numeric(.[[2]])) %>% select(-2)

>df

ID        Days Score1 Score2
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 patient1     0     NA      1
2 patient1    25      2     10
3 patient1   248      3      3
4 patient1   353      4      4
5 patient2   100      5      5
6 patient2   150     NA      7
7 patient3   503     NA      6
8 patient3   538      6     NA
```

Comment: This code leaves a lot of double values for ```Days``` in a larger sample dataset. I will try to edit it so that it works

Comment: I solved it by adding ```df %>% group_by(ID, Days) %>% mutate(Score.xx = dplyr::first(na.omit(Score.x)), Score.yy = dplyr::first(na.omit(Score.y))) %>% select(-Score.x,-Score.y) %>% unique()```.

Unfortunately, when using your code on a sample of 1000 rows from my real data, only 75 non-NA values remained (out of 86) so there is still something going wrong.

Comment: That means some of the other exceptions are not shown in the sample data above.  Perhaps you can provide a new reprex or describe other exceptions.